# Campo input não está carregando valor padrão "value"

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap

Tenho o campo:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label style="color:white" for="valor">Valor</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" value = "0" class="form-control" step="any" name="valor" ng-model="contato.valor" required>
```

...

Porém o campo não está inicializando com o valor definido no value.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Acredito que ele irá considerar o `ng-model`. Tente setar o valor default em `$scope.valor` ou usar `ng-value`.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque você tem um **ng-model**. O value desse input é o ng-model, provavelmente você não está passando nada para esse model, por isso que ele vai vazio.

Vá no seu controller e insira um valor para esse Model, no seu caso, você está querendo que o value seja igual a 0.

Então vá no seu controller e coloque:

```
$scope.contato.valor = 0
```

**Leia mais sobre o** [Ng-Model aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)